# MySQL: Select count of a group with the id of last record

Tags: mysql

Here is my table called `logs`:

```
id    package    log
====================
0     first      log0
1     first      log1
2     second     log2
```

And I want the query result to be like this:

```
package    count    last_log_id
===============================
first      2        1
second     1        2
```

So far, my searches led me to this:

```
SELECT package, COUNT(*) FROM logs GROUP BY package
```

This helped me getting the count of each group by package.

```
SELECT a1.package, COUNT(*),a1.id 
FROM logs a1 LEFT JOIN logs a2 
ON (a1.package = a2.package AND a1.id < a2.id) 
WHERE a2.id IS NULL 
GROUP BY a1.package
```

And this helped me getting the id of the last log, but the count is wrong!

```
package    count    last_log_id
===============================
first      1        1
second     1        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first attempt is correct, and you may use the `MAX` function to find the latest log `id` for each package:

```
SELECT
    package,
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    MAX(id) AS last_log_id
FROM logs
GROUP BY package;
```